# Returning %40 to an @ symbol

Tags: php, html

```
dev%40bionic%2Dcomms%2Eco%2Euk
```

I want to turn the above back in to readable text. Can anyone tell me how? Thanks

EDIT
Forgive my oversight, PHP is the language of choice!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You haven't said which language, but in many the function you want is urldecode

(Looking at your other questions, you probably want PHP. It is [urldecode](https://www.php.net/urldecode) there :))

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript: `decodeURIComponent("dev%40bionic%2Dcomms%2Eco%2Euk")`

Comment: unescape doesn't work for non-ASCII characters and is deprecated, use decodeURIComponent instead (same goes for escape -> encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 2):

Although this wasn't what you were after, for reference in C# you can use HttpUtility.UrlEncode

EDIT

UrlDecode :P

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx